# Insert resampled index into a tuple

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples

I have a set of data (panda dataframe) which looks like this:

```
           date   time  steps
0    2020-11-23  20:44     48
1    2020-11-23  20:45     33
2    2020-11-23  21:15     38
3    2020-11-23  21:16     20
4    2020-11-23  21:17    102
```

After resampling to get the time by minutes:

```
df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df["date"] + ' ' + df["time"]), inplace=True)
df = df.drop(columns=["date", "time"])
df = df.resample("1min").first().fillna("0")
```

I obtain a new df which contains just index and steps at every minute:

```
                    steps
2020-11-23 20:44:00    48
2020-11-23 20:45:00    33
2020-11-23 20:46:00     0
2020-11-23 20:47:00     0
2020-11-23 20:48:00     0
```

Now I'm facing an issue when adding the index into a tuple in order to insert the data into MySQL. Using the code:

```
subset = df[["index", "steps"]]
tuples = [tuple(x) for x in subset.to_numpy()]
```

Does not really work since obviously there is no column named Index, I also tried to rename the index column but it is still not accessible.

Is there a way to insert the index into a tuple?

Comment: `df = df.resample("1min").first().fillna("0").reset_index()` before `subset`.

Comment: Thanks, I think this is the best solution as it generates a column named index that you can reference as df["index"], so very simple

Answer (score 0):

to call the index use df.index if it's not named

```
tuples = list(zip(df.index, df['steps']))

to see index name use df.index.name
to set it use df.index.name = 'myindex'
to clear it use df.index.name = ''
```